# Passing an id to a url link in Django

Tags: python, django, variables, url

I have the option of deleting one project. So I need to know which project the user needs to delete.

1- I have the name of the project in an Array.

**views.py:**

```
def index(request):
 cursor = connection.cursor()
 cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
 bases = cursor.fetchall()
 arrayBases = []
 for i in bases:
    for j in i:
        arrayBases.append(j)


return render(request, 'index.html', {
    'arrayBases': arrayBases
})
```

So I make a table in the Template.

**index.html:**

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <th>Nombre del proyecto</th>
  <th>Acción</th>
</tr>
{% if arrayBases %}
  {% for base in arrayBases %}
  <tr>
    <td> {{ base }} </td>
    <td>
      <a href="{% **url 'deleteProject' base** %}" id="{{ base }}">
        <img height="15px" src="{% static "icons/delete.svg" %}">
      </a>
    </td>

  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

In the link, I want to send the name of the project as a parameter to other view. So this is my url.

**urls.py:**

```
url(r'^deleteProject/(?P<base>[a-z]+[A-Z]*[0-9]*)$', views.deleteProject, name="deleteProject"),
```

but I have this error.

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Can you provide the exact error that you getting?

Comment: This is the error: [link](http://s31.postimg.org/odla1rll7/Screen_Shot_2016_04_21_at_20_10_08.png)